# Android Viewflow go to view with a button

Tags: android, button, viewgroup

I am trying to make a nice horizontal viewgroup with the [ViewFlow](https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) class.

I want to combine it with buttons. For example, when I click button 2 I go to view 2 of the viewgroup. Is that possible? I currently got this:

```
public class HousingActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

ViewFlow viewFlow;
ListView listView;

HousingViewflowAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.housing_activity);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
    setOnClickListner(this, this, new int[] { R.id.housing_button1,
            R.id.housing_button2, R.id.housing_button3,
            R.id.housing_button4 });
    adapter = new HousingViewflowAdapter(this);
    viewFlow.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewFlow.setOnViewSwitchListener(new ViewSwitchListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSwitched(View view, int position) {

        }
    });

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.housing_view1_listview);
    ArrayList<Community> communityList = new ArrayList<Community>();
            // Some dummy data
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        communityList.add(new Community("Place " + new Random().nextInt(),
                new Random().nextInt(), 000000000, ""));
    }
    listView.setAdapter(new MainListViewAdapter(this, 0, communityList));
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // viewFlow.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    super.onClick(v);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.housing_button1:  
        break;
    case R.id.housing_button2:
        break;
    case R.id.housing_button3:
        break;
    case R.id.housing_button4:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into:

```
viewFlow.setSelection(int position)
```

Comment: It's not working. It does something else then go to the view that has been clicked..

Answer (score 0):

Ah ! I found it !

```
viewFlow.setAdapter(adapter,number);
```

The number being the page you want to show